# О физиках и лириках

Tags: общие-вопросы

Как вы думаете, правильно ли рассуждать, что, если человек совершенно не разбирается в математике, это простительно, а вот, если он не читал Пастернака или не помнит, кто убил старушку-процентщицу, то он ограниченный неуч?
То есть, если говорить о моем мнении, я, хоть и уважаю математиков, но все-таки соглашусь с этим. Но все-таки почему приоритеты расставлены именно так?

[image]

Comment: Если  обсуждать  диалог  наших  персонажей,  то  женщина  просто  бестактна  и  агрессивна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как составить мнение о незнакомом человеке, как нарисовать для себя его портрет?
Общекультурная  информация  воспринимается как своеобразный тест, позволяющий  сделать определенный вывод, а её конкретное содержание  отбирается обществом в процессе развития и постоянно меняется.

Не обязательно, к примеру, быть знатоком творчества Пастернака, но желательно иметь представление о его вкладе в мировую культуру. Ваше мнение на эту тему – это дополнительный штрих к рисунку вашего «я». С десяток таких ответов-мнений, а также обязательная оценка правильности, выразительности, экспрессивности  речи – и портрет готов. «Какой интересный человек», - скажут про вас. Или подумают: «Ну и невежда, скучно с ним, поговорить не о чем». Или решат: «Надо от него держаться подальше, агрессивный какой-то».

Что касается математики, то она подобных возможностей не имеет и служит в основном для оценки правильности логического мышления. Но логика – это только один из частных способов познания мира, в то время как интуиция иногда дает более полную картину – Пушкин, к примеру, был великим мыслителем, но при этом плохо разбирался в математике.

Соответственно, знание точных наук не является обязательным качеством культурного человека, к тому же образность (художественность) мышления иногда прямо противопоставляется  математической логике. С другой стороны, полное отсутствие логичных мнений и поступков у человека – это тоже не лучший вариант.

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле это несовсем так. Человека, не знающего, какие планеты есть в Солнечной системе, и не способного без калькулятора сложить два двузначных числа, вряд ли кто сочтет культурным. Другое дело, что в "джентельменский набор" образованного человека знаний формул входит меньше, чем знаний стихов. Причина проста - в повседневной жизни нам, как правило, нужны не сами формулы, а лишь выводы из них, поэтому технические знания на обывательском уровне тоже часто имеют гуманитарный характер. Мы все знаем, что для того, чтобы приподнять тяжелое, нужен рычаг, но формулу, по которой можно вычислить необходимую длинну рычага, назовут немногие. Этим и объясняется, что при поверхностном взгляде гуманитарные науки актуальнее в жизни.

Comment: Формулы не нужны, а стихи-то зачем нужны? В повседневной жизни?

Comment: @Niemand, стихи нужны в повседневной жизни для общения. Чтобы понимать человека, который вдруг скажет, что он весенней гулкой ранью проскакал на розовом коне. Как-то читал историю про то, как израильский психиатр хотел отправить в психушку русскоязычного призывника из-за того, что тот изобразил кота учёного, который сказки рассказывает и песни поёт. Остановило психиатра от этого шага только то, что его коллеги на рисунке этого кота тоже опознали.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, тут разговор не совсем о физиках и лириках. А картинка вообще более забавна, чем объективна. К тому же она о мужчинах и женщинах, а совсем не о физиках-лириках.
Явно сексистская штучка.

Как математик в душе, увы, не состоявшийся по воле судеб, и еще менее состоявшийся лирик, скажу только одно. Грань между "как можно" и не "бери в голову" определяется разницей между инструментарием в широком смысле и результатом производства. 
Культурное наследие и Пастернак в числе прочего - ценность конечная, продукт потребления всего общества.
А производная и прочая физика-математика - средство производства. Для профессионалов.

Comment: Математика тоже конечная ценность. По крайней мере школьная. Она развивает мозг – куда уж конечнее!

Comment: Всё правильно о конечном общественном продукте. К примеру, самые разные люди приходят в музеи любоваться художественными полотнами, но никто, кроме профессионалов, не любуется формулами.

Answer (score 0):

Никто так приоритеты не расставлял, это вы свою точку зрения выдаете за общепринятую.

Разбираться в математике и знать математику на школьном уровне – это "две большие разницы". Школьная математика – это не математика, это её азы. Точнее, азы азов. Задумайтесь: почти вся школьная математика была известна ещё две тыщи лет назад! И даже раньше. И есть темы, которых в школьной математике нет, но они уже были известны в те времена. Впечатляет?

Так что владение школьной математикой я бы сравнил не с Пастернаком, а с элементарным умением писать и читать.

Comment: @Niemand, это "наследие" того периода российской и советской истории, когда "в свете" было принято "покорять" женщину стихами.
На математические формулы они как-то "не ведутся". Проверено. :(

Answer (score 0):

Культура - это система обычаев. Система обычаев, обеспечивающая стабильное существование сообществ живых существ., в т.ч. человека. В разных условиях существования - разные системы. В сообществе бушменов - своя система, в сообществе буддистов своя система, в сообществе финансистов - своя. Кто не вполне соблюдает обычаи системы того сообщество отодвигает на периферию, а то и исключает. В сообществе нефтяников хорошо и ибез Пастернака, и без Ван Гога: знай только и делай отлично свою работу и никто не попрекнет Лобачевским, а будут уважать. Но если хочешь вращаться в сферах..., то будь добёр. То есть, если ты не в своей системе, то не обращай внимания на упреки чуждых тебе по духу людей. А если тебя это обижа-а-ет, то начни соответствовать. И тебя зауважают там. Но не дай бог им сунуться  со своим Пастернаком в нефтяники.

Comment: Из Пастернака помню только "...Свеча горела...". Только это и понравилось. Почему? Потому что Пастернак писал для избранных, а не для народа. Знал ли он народ? Не уверен. Бродский - знал! Пастернак, таким образом, не является оселком, на котором проверяется "культурность" человека (что в нынешнее время очень престижно применять для качественной оценки человека)... Человек многогранен. Культура только одна из его граней. Физик, не читавший В. Шукшина, не много потеряет в профессиональном плане. Физики-гуманитарии будут его ценить, но в душе быть к нему снисходительными. И так по всем вопросам.